# .htaccess error : The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I have a php file which is home.php

my url on localhost is

`http://localhost:8888/photo/home.php`

I want to remove `.php` from the url

so i create `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home?$ home.php
```

but i keep getting this error

> The requested URL /photo/home was not found on this server.

Comment: the `^` means to start searching at the beginning of the string. You probably want `^/?photo/home`

Comment: Hello @Cfreak . Thank you for your reply but this doesn't work either `RewriteRule ^/?photo/home home.php`

Comment: You probably need to use this: `RewriteRule ^(/?photo)/home $1/home.php`. The `/photo` needs to be in the rewritten URL. Reason for  the backreference is, that there may or may not be a slash at the beginning of the matched URL, depending on where this RewriteRule is located.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ensure your .htaccess file is in the base directory of your project. Next, follow [these htaccess rules](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules) to set up your redirect.

The .htaccess solution you might be looking for is:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Neither a file nor a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^photo/home$ photo/home.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this, in your photo directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

# neither a file nor a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I put the `.htaccess` code in the root `.htaccess`. It works when I create a new `.htaccess` in the subdomain folder on the same level with public_html folder and fill it with the RewriteRule needed